# SQL server cambio o encripta mi contraseña

Tags: sql-server, ssms

El problema es este, uso `SQLServer` 12.0.2000 lo he consumido desde `c#` y `java` sin ningún problema por los últimos meses, pero ha dejado de hacer conexiones, observe que a mis logins les aparentemente les había cambiado la contraseña, por ejemplo al Usuario 'Practicas' con contraseña '***' (123),ahora le aparecía la contraseña *************** de 15 caracteres, pero al iniciar sesión en el management studio la contraseña 123 me permite iniciar sesión, pero no así desde java ni c# con cadenas de conexión que antes funcionaban.

Comment: Siempre muestra `***************`  cuando vas a la sección de seguridad de usuario, como forma de que otro usuario no sepa el largo exacto de la contraseña. No tiene nada que ver con encriptar o cambiar contraseñas, es simplemente como se **muestra** en esa pantalla (esto es por diseño)

Comment: Ok, pero mi duda es que anteriormente si mostraba *** y ahora no funcionan mis cadenas de conexion

Comment: La verdad es que dudo que alguna vez haya mostrado `***` en la pantalla de SQL Server Management Studio. Acerca de que no funcionan las cadenas de conexión, claramente el error está en otro lado, ya que mencionas que sí puedes iniciar la sesión en management studio, lo que significa que la contraseña es correcta

Comment: Gracias ya vi por alguna razón el usuario ya no tenia permisos, ahora otra duda ¿qué hago con esta pregunta? la cierro, la borro, que procede, además ¿te doy like mejor respuesta o algo así?

Comment: Creo que lo mejor sería que tú mismo respondieras la pregunta comentando cuál fue el problema y la solución, y después aceptes esa respuesta

Answer (score 1, accepted):

El Login de sql no contaba con los permisos necesarios para acceder a la base de datos.